# Optimising a SQL query with a huge where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I am working on a system (with Laravel) where users can fill a few filters to get the data they need. 
Data is not prepared real time, once the filters are set, a job is pushed to the queue and once the query finishes a CSV file is created. Then the user receives an email with the file which was created so that they can download it.

I have seen some errors in the jobs where it took longer than 30 mins to process one job and when I checked I have seen some users created filter with more than 600 values.

This filter values are translated like this:

```
SELECT filed1, 
       field2, 
       field6 
FROM   table 
       INNER JOIN table2 
               ON table.id = table2.cid 
/* this is how we try not to give same data to the users again so we used NOT IN */ 
WHERE  table.id NOT IN(SELECT data_id 
                       FROM   data_access 
                       WHERE  data_user = 26) 
       AND ( /* this bit is auto populated with the filter values */ 
           table2.filed_a = 'text a' 
            OR table2.filed_a = 'text b' 
            OR table2.filed_a = 'text c' )
```

Well I was not expecting users to go wild and fine tune with a huge filter set. It is okay for them to do this but need a solution to make this query quicker.

One way is to create a temp table on the fly with the filter values and covert the query for `INNER JOIN` but not sure if it would increase the performance. 
Also, given that in a normal day system would need to create at least 40-ish temp tables and delete them afterwards. Would this become another issue in the long run?

I would love to hear any other suggestions that may help me solve this issue other then temp table method.

Comment: Have you checked the `EXPLAIN` plan?  I ask this, because the subquery in the `WHERE` is _not_ correlated with the outer query, meaning that MySQL can probably run it once, and cache the results.  So, I'm not sure that would be your biggest bottleneck here.

Comment: Indeed, that the subquery in the `NOT IN` expression is not correlated seems very suspicious to me, especially in light of the associated comment.

Comment: you already try to change WHERE  table.id NOT IN (sub query) with a LEFT JOIN data_access ON data_access.data_id  = table.id WHERE data_access.data_id IS NULL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT ?.filed1, ?.field2, ?.field6  -- qualify column names (but no effect on performance)
FROM table t JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t.id = t2.cid 

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM data_access da
                  WHERE t.id = da.data_id AND da.data_user = 26
                 ) AND
     t2.filed_a IN ('text a', 'text b', 'text c') ;
```

Then I would recommend indexes.  Most likely:

- `table2(filed_a, cid)`
- `table1(id)`  (may not be necessary if `id` is already the primary key)
- `data_access(data_id, data_user)`

You can test this as your own query.  I don't know how to get Laravel to produce this (assuming it meets your performance objectives).